# INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS select from a table sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a normal sql query that dynamically calls the column from a certain table. I've read some forum regarding on how to get the list of the column using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`, but I want to select the column from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS from my table`.

For example:

```
SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'OPOR' AND LEFT(COLUMN_NAME, 2) = 'U_') FROM OPOR
```

But it return the column name only. Not the values from this column in my table. So my question is, is that possible to return the value from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and select it from my table? My example column is, `U_NewColumn`. So the result should be: `SELECT U_NewColumn FROM OPOR`

Comment: you can write dynamic query

Comment: @Dhaval can you give me an example for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is helpful when you want to construct a dynamic query where you get the list of table/column based on some filter you have. In your case. what you want to do is to create a dynamic sql where you want to get the data of the first column which starts from `U_`

You would do something like this.

```
DECLARE @Variable NVARCHAR(200) = 'SELECT '
SELECT TOP 1 @Variable = @Variable + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME,']') + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME,']')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'OPOR' AND LEFT(COLUMN_NAME, 2) = 'U_'

EXEC sp_executeSQL @Variable
```

If you want more than one column, you would do something like this

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100) = 'OPOR'
DECLARE @Variable NVARCHAR(200)
SELECT @Variable = 'SELECT ' + STUFF((
SELECT', ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME,']')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND LEFT(COLUMN_NAME, 2) = 'U_'
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') + ' FROM ' + @TableName


PRINT  @Variable
EXEC sp_executeSQL @Variable
```

Comment: appreciate it. But what if there are more columns not TOP 1?

Comment: If you use TOP without an order by you are not guaranteed which row will be returned. In this example if you want the "first" column you would need to order by ORDINAL_POSITION.